# Media notification player buttons disables - Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11, android-mediasession

I have a bug with the media notification player using exo player. The play/pause, previous, next button don't work.

This happens with a Samsung Galaxy A10S with Android 11.

I would like to know how to reproduce the bug, because I don't have that phone but I already tried in other phones with Android 11 and all works well.

Thanks in advance